# org-mode-agenda is taking too much screen estate

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to change the size of org-mode-agenda on opening so that when opening the agenda, it doesn't open so large (saving me having to resize it)?

Answer (score 1):

I am using org version 9.0.8 and for me there is "org-agenda-window-setup" and "org-agenda-window-frame-fractions". You need to set org-agenda-window-setup to reorganize-frame and then fractions to something that fits you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Matthias said, you can control whether the agenda opens horizontally or vertically. There are two threshold values `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold` by which org determines this automatically, but you can also force it; here's what I have in my `.emacs` so that the agenda always opens vertically:

```
;; Open agenda vertically by default
(defadvice org-agenda (around split-vertically activate)
  (let (
    (split-width-threshold 40)    ; or whatever width makes sense for you
    (split-height-threshold nil)) ; but never horizontally
ad-do-it))
```